# My app deployment to cloud foundry fails on

Tags: .net, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

The command I used was: ibmcloud target --cf

The error I receive is given below:

-----> Finalizing Dotnet Core
**ERROR** Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version o
f dotnet-runtime to install
Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 12
Exit status 223
Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 stopping instance e5256fa6-702e-41f
2-8c49-039400712a85
Cell 0f7012eb-9e32-4fdf-ba92-85aee4639139 destroying container for instance e
5256fa6-702e-41f2-8c49-039400712a85
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED

Comment: I am new to cloud foundry and don't know how to solve this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how we expect questions.

Comment: Can you more information like manifest.yml, details about your .NET project?

Comment: yes,my manifest.yml has the following:
 applications:
 - name: <App-Name>
   random-route: true
   memory: 128M


I tried pushing via below command today, cf push APP-NAME -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack.git

It is still giving error:


   -----> Finalizing Dotnet Core
          **ERROR** Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version o
f dotnet-runtime to install
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 12
   Exit status 223
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### after a lot of work and help from people I found out that I was using the wrong buildpack. If your application is built in ASP.Net framework 4.5 or newer then you need to use the hwc pack. Also, your manifest.yml will need changes. This is my manifest.yml.

applications:

- name: 
  random-route: true
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc-buildpack.git
  env:
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: true

This works. Create a toolchain build and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and worked for me

- Installed [IBM Cloud CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli#step1-install-idt)
- Followed the instructions in the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry?topic=cloud-foundry-getting_started-dotnet) to clone a getting started dotnet application
- Cloned the sample app and `cd` into the folder
- Run

```
ibmcloud cf push
```

You should see a random URL generated with the todo app

> Use a Cloud Foundry CLI that's managed by IBM to work with Cloud
> Foundry resources through the IBM Cloud CLI. If you have a separate
> Cloud Foundry CLI (cf) installation, don't use both ibmcloud cf
> commands and cf commands in the same context. Instead, use only
> ibmcloud cf [command] to manage resources in the IBM Cloud CLI
> context. More info [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_cli#ibmcloud_cf)

Comment: Hi, this is what I did and then it gave me the above mentioned error. I think may be because my application is not built in core. I saw in one of the forums, they had mentioned about uploading a zip and publishing it before pushing it. Can you tell me how to do that?